# Why do X applications show a question mark as TTY in ps's result?

Tags: tty, ps

```
$ ps -ef | head -n 1 && ps -ef | grep calc
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user1     524014    5382  0 10:21 ?        00:00:01 gnome-calculator
user1     532125  510665  0 10:36 pts/4    00:00:00 grep calc
```

I thought that only daemons would have `?` as TTY, but obviously Gnome Calculator is not a daemon. I know it's running on TTY2, which is the TTY used by my Gnome session. So why does the `ps` result show `?` in the TTY column ?

[EDIT]

I get the idea that Gnome Calculator is not directly attached to a TTY, because it has been launched through a graphical shell (Gnome Shell). I thought that by going up the process tree I'd get a process attached to TTY2, but that's never the case :

```
$ ps -f | head -n 1 && ps -ef | grep calc
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user1     524014    5382  0 10:21 ?        00:00:01 gnome-calculator
user1     578611  552619  0 11:58 pts/5    00:00:00 grep calc

$ ps -f -p 5382
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user1       5382    5131  4 juin10 ?       00:42:26 /usr/bin/gnome-shell

$ ps -f -p 5131
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user1       5131       1  0 juin10 ?       00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user

$ echo $DISPLAY 
:1
```

No process up the chain is attached to TTY2. But obviously Gnome Calculator is currently displayed on TTY2. Is there a command to find out on which TTY a given process is currently displayed ? (or maybe on which `$DISPLAY`) ?

Comment: Consider `ps -ef | grep -E '^UID|[c]alc'` to search for a process called `calc` Any character is in square brackets `[ ]` so that `grep` can't match itself

Comment: Great ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ps will display a question mark for any thread not immediately attached to a tty. ([a terminal from which the process can be controlled](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Terminal.html))

That is of course the case for kernel threads and misc other daemons.

But this is also necessarily the case for X-clients.

Did you launch gnome-calculator directly from a standard tty ? No of course ! would you find a tty under which typing Ctrl-C would just kill it ? No again !
You certainly launched it from your graphical interface that is to say, logically some X-client. => No tty attached.

However, if you have been launching your X-server from some tty using startx, you'll notice that the X-server iitself is indeed attached to that tty.

---

EDIT following comments :

I cannot tell for you but as far as I am concerned, looking at :

```
1 S acoswt    1817     1  0  80   0 -  1036 -      07:02 tty4     00:00:00 dbus-launch --exit-with-session startplasma-x11
```

my desktop environment (KDE-Plasma) is launched by… the **dbus… daemon.** I suspect you get something similar with gnome. Therefore… again… no controlling terminal as such.

Comment: @ChennyStar yours appears launched by the systemd… daemon. No controlling terminal again.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this question.

The first, why does ps show "?" is reasonably simple. The procps library looks at the 7th field on the process' stat file and tries to parse that into a TTY name.

```
$ ps -o pid,tty,cmd -C gnome-calculator
    PID TT       CMD
  74426 ?        gnome-calculator
$ cut -f 1-9 -d' ' /proc/74426/stat
74426 (gnome-calculato) S 2325 2325 2325 0 -1 4194304
```

See the zero after 2325 and -1? That's the TTY device ID which the kernel is basically saying "don't know" or "not applicable".

Start it on the command line in gnome-terminal and you do get a TTY because it now has a controlling terminal.

```
$ ps -o pid,tty,cmd -C gnome-calculator
    PID TT       CMD
  75446 pts/2    gnome-calculator
$ cut -f 1-9 -d' ' /proc/75446/stat
75446 (gnome-calculato) S 72016 75446 72016 34818 75721 4194304
```

The 34818 is the device ID, with [some odd bit masking and shifting](https://gitlab.com/git-mirrors/glibc/-/blob/master/bits/sysmacros.h#L39) you get that becoming the major ID of 136 and minor of 2 which are the IDs of /dev/pts/2

Secondly, the reason why the first calculator doesn't have a TTY device ID is based on how X works because the computer your display was on could be different to the computer the calculator program was running.

So while your X server runs on TTY2 your calculator program is not running from that TTY. If you hunt around looking for your session process (probably gnome-session) you'll find that is running on tty2.